# Is it possible for Visual Studio 2008 Automatically create XML Comments tags without "Generate XML documentation file" checked (VB.NET only)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, xml-comments

When in VS 2008 if a developer hits the ''' it generates the XML comment tags for you, but this only works when the project setting for "Generate XML documentation file" is checked.

**Is there a way to tell VS to generate the XML Comment tags, regardless of the project setting?**

I think it is possible that someone may want comments but not create a XML documentation file.

In this case I am exceeding the current Team Settings, yet other developers don't want me to change this project setting. This forces me to flip this back before checking in the project.

I have the same problem with other Project settings like "code Analysis".

This is only a problem for VB.NET projects.

Comment: It works in C#, so there could be a way to fix this in VB.NET

Comment: Appears to work is VS11 beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No for VB.NET and VS2008.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=477562

Comment: C# seems to have an added feature for the editor; I can't imagine it would be that hard to add for VB.

See:

Options
>Text Editor
>>C#
>>>Advanced

Panel:
XML Documentation Comments

Check Box:
Generate XML Documentation comments for ///

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post however I have found a work around that may work for you depending if you team members just want the XML comments functionality and not the XML files.

1) In your project properties ensure that `Generate XML documention` file is checked.
2) Click the `Build Events`  button
3) Into the `Post-build event command line` box enter the command

`Del "$(OutDir)$(ProjectName).xml"`

Now after each build it will remove the XML comment file.

Note: For some reason if it exists from a previous build it will not delete it so manually delete it the first time.

Comment: In my case it's more of the side effects; warnings in the IDE; when all I want is to add comment to the code. But this may work for others. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, I almost never want these when the projects are in the same solution. This also allows me to axe the XMLs from other projects (mine is never pulled into another). Del "*.xml" just remember this if you ever add an XML that's supposed to be there!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it will *always* create the xml comments....the Generate XML documentation I think only affects whether those comments are then compiled into an xml file.

Is it behaving like this on everyone's machine?

Comment: No, I have confirmed on 2 machines that it will NOT create XML Comment tags unless the "Generate XML documentation file" is check. C# works as expected, but VB.NET does not.

Answer (score 0):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=477562

but obviously you already know that since you opened up the Connect issue.